# microsoft jscript runtime error object doesn't support property or method 'caroufredsel'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Hello I keep receiving this error on page load.What will be the alternative of this property .

```
<script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider();
        });

        $(function () {
            $('#work').carouFredSel({
                width: '100%',
                scroll: 1,
                auto: false,
                pagination: false,
                prev: '.prev_item',
                next: '.next_item'
            });

            $("#work").touchwipe({
                wipeLeft: function () { $('.next_item').trigger('click'); },
                wipeRight: function () { $('.prev_item').trigger('click'); }
            });
        });

        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#demo-side-bar').removeAttr('style');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you loaded the `carouFredSel` plugin library?

Comment: Sir actually i have used ready-mate templates for my project. How can i know whether it is loaded or not

Comment: thank you sir error resolved i have just followed the instruction given in this link http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel